# Python PyAudio ошибка при попытке запуска скрипта

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio

при попытке запуска любого скрипта с модулем PyAudio
выводит такую ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\K.E.T.R.I.N___Official\ss.py", line 85, in <module>
    with m as source:
  File "E:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 138, in __enter__
    self.audio.open(
  File "E:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels
```

Comment: Какая версия питона?

Comment: @Эникейщик  Python 3.8.5

Comment: Возможно, pyaudio на этой версии не работает. Попробуйте запустить скрипт на 3.6.

Comment: @Эникейщик Не запускается